# How to search for Entries that have a particular Category set within a Matrix field in the Control Panel?

Tags: craft3, matrix, categories, control-panel, search

I have an arrangement like this:

```
Entry type 'people'
└ Matrix field 'offices'
  └ Block type 'office'
    └ Category field 'building'
```

On the Entries screen, how can I search for `people` that have a particular `building` Category assigned within the `offices` Matrix?

Note: the `offices` and `building` fields both have "Use this field’s values as search keywords" checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple answer: you just type the category name (no matter whether it's being set within a Matrix field).

The reason this didn't work in the first place was that my search index hadn't been updated properly by the auto-running task that triggered after an XML import I did with the Feed Me plugin.

I simply had to [rebuild the search indexes manually](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/searching.html#rebuilding-your-search-indexes) to fix the issue.